# How to finish all previous async functions in flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I just created button that will run async function. The function will wait 4 seconds and prints.If I click button several times it will print all clicks. I want to after click the button, remove the all previous async functions and leave the last click.This is my following code.

```
void asyncFunction(){
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),() async{
      print('something');
    });
  }
```

So how to finish all previous async functions in flutter?

Comment: Please add more information, But what I answered I think you want to cancel async function here the link may help you https://dart.academy/how_cancel_future/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel the previous running timer every time you run your function. Declare a timer into your state as a pointer to the current async execution.

```
Timer _timer;

void asyncFunction() {
  _timer?.cancel();
  _timer = Timer(
    const Duration(seconds: 4),
    () => print('something'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a Timer to stop it later

```
Timer timer;

void asyncFunction() {
    timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      print('something');
    });

   onPressed: () {
  if(timer != null)
   timer.cancel();

   asyncFunction();
 }
```